# Eloquent Javascript: Chessboard

Tags: javascript, eloquent

Write a program that creates a string that represents an 8×8 grid, using newline characters to separate lines. At each position of the grid there is either a space or a “#” character. The characters should form a chess board.

My code keeps creating an 8 x 8 structure with all hashes. 
Can someone offer some advice to edit my code?

```
 var size = 8;

 var str = "";

 var altern = false;
 var line = 1;

 while (line <= size) {
     var character = 1;
     while (character <= size) {
         if (altern) {
             if (character % 2 === 0) {
                 str += "#";
                 console.log(character);
                 console.log(str);

             } else {
                 str += " ";
                 console.log(character);
                 console.log(str);
             }

         } else {
             if (character % 2 === 0) {
                 str += " ";
                 console.log(character);
                 console.log(str);
             } else {
                 str += "#";
                 console.log(character);
                 console.log(str);
             }
         }

         altern = !altern;
         character++;

     }

     str += "\n";
     line++;
 }

 console.log(str);
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with more explanations and less code? Right now it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Here is a one liner, `if (column - row%2) % 2` == 0

Answer (score 1):

By using both `altern` and `character % 2` you select the branch with the # every iteration. Use only one of the two.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out how to answer this myself until I found OP's code. Here is what I found would work:

```
var size = prompt("What is the size?");
var str = "";
var line = 0; 
//Instead of using 1, use 0. It'll make sense in the next comment.

while (line < size) {
    var character = 0; // Changed this to 0 as well.
        while (character < size) {
            if (line % 2 === 0){

            /*Instead of using logic negate(altern = !altern), you could use one of the variables
            you already have. Changing line = 1 to line = 0, we now can write the conditon above. 
            Where the first line holds true, because 0 % 2 === 0 is true.*/ 
                
                if (character % 2 === 0) {
                    str += " "; // I switched the string values around, to get what is resembled in the book.
                    console.log(character);
                    console.log(str);
                } else {
                    str += "#"; // Here
                    console.log(character);
                    console.log(str);
                }
            } else {
                if (character % 2 === 0) {
                str += "#"; // Here
                console.log(character);
                console.log(str);
                } else {
                str += " "; // Here
                console.log(character);
                console.log(str);
                }
            }
        character++;
        }

    str += "\n";
    line++;
}
alert(str);
//Changed this so the final result is easier to see, rather than in the jumbled mess of the console.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want to toggle `altern` with each new **line**, not with each **square**.

You have a loop inside a loop here. Move your `altern` toggle code from the inner loop to the outer loop.

```
while (line <= size) {
     var character = 1;
     while (character <= size) {
         // inner loop code here
         character++;
     }

     // Outer loop end code. HERE is where you toggle altern
     str += "\n";
     line++;
     altern = !altern;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below one works but I replaced spaces with Os (capital o's) and a little change in your code.

```
 var size = 8;

 var str = "";

 var altern = false;
 var line = 1;

 while (line <= size) {
     var character = 1;
     while (character <= size) {
       console.log('altern: ' + altern + 'character: ' + character);
         if (altern) {
             if (character % 2 === 0) {
                 str += "O";
                 console.log(character);
                 console.log(str);

             } else {
                 str += "#";
                 console.log(character);
                 console.log(str);
             }

         } else {
             if (character % 2 === 0) {
                 str += "O";
                 console.log(character);
                 console.log(str);
             } else {
                 str += "#";
                 console.log(character);
                 console.log(str);
             }
         }

         altern = !altern;
         character++;

     }

     str += "\n";
     line++;
 }

//  console.log(str);
alert(str);
```

This one works, but not, I suggest you to try to re-write this code in a better way. Hint: pay attention to what @koenpeters said.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using all those loops you could do this:

```
var width = 8,
    height = 8,
    str = new Array(1 + (width * height + height) / 2).join('# ').replace(new RegExp('(.{' + width + '}).', 'g'), '$1\n');
```

Works as long as width isn't even while at the same time height is odd.

If you just need it for this one specific case you could also get rid of a bit of the overhead and just use this:

```
var str = new Array(37).join('# ').replace(/(.{8})./g, '$1\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a while loop and over-repetition of your cases based on location (i.e. even vs odd) use two for loops and one case statement for whether a location needs a # vs " ". Store them to a var, then print the var once it is complete.

```
var board = "";
var countX = 0;
var countY = 0;
var size = 8;

for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if((countX + countY) % 2 == 0) {
            board += " ";  
        }
        else {
            board += "#";
        }
        countX++;
    }
    board += "\n";
    countY++; 
}
console.log(board);
```

board output:

```
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # #
```

Answer (score 0):

i would have tackle this problem by first using a while loop to printing out a line of 8 harsh (########) symbol , then repeat it 8 times vertically using another loop,  write a test condition that changes the value of y when the value of both iteration are even numbers.

```
const size = 8
for(let i = 0; i < size; i++){
    let y = " "
    let cols = 0;
    if(i % 2 == 0){
       y = "";
    }else{
       y = " ";
    }  
    while(cols < size){
      if( cols % 2 == 0){
         y = y + "#"}
      else{
         y = y + " "
      }
    rows++
    }
  console.log(y)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Nested For Loop will work the best for this solution as below ---

```
//to get the input from the user for any size of the array
var charSize=prompt('Enter Number');
var boardChar = "";

//outer loop
for (let i = 1; i <= charSize; i++) {

//inner loop
  for (let j = 1; j <= charSize; j++) {

//Check for even column
let evenCol = (i + j) % 2;

if (evenCol == 0) { 
  boardChar += " ";
} else { 
  boardChar += "#";
}

}

boardChar += "\n"; 
}
console.log(boardChar);

 //OUTPUT 
  [Output Image][1]
```

Answer (score -1):

The essential thing to realise is that given the *N* th row, its first square will be black if N is odd, and white otherwise.

Also, if the first square of a given row is black, then for a given column *M*, the square will be black if M is odd, and white if M is even.

Similarly, if the first square is white, then for a column *M*, the square will be white if *M* is odd, and black otherwise.

Hope that helps.

EDIT:

try this if you’re a fan of unreadable code:

```
for i in range(8):
    s = ''
    for j in range(8):
        if (i - j%2) % 2 == 0:
            s = s + "#"
        else: s = s + 'O'
    print s
```

Answer (score -2):

I also learn JavaScript currently. I was stuck on that for one day. The only thing, that I realize, that if you want to do something useful in JavaScript use loops.

I don't have an idea about complicated coding, but loops could easily do things, that seems at first to be complicated.

Here is my version:

**let b = ""**       //**just create an empty string, because if you won't do that, loop will print out symbols, numbers etc in a single column, but if you use empty string you can in future write symbols inside that string, which allows you to expand string horisontally

**let size = 8**        //**since loops start at 0 to infinity, you must take it into account,

**for (let i = 0; i < size; i++)**       //**create first loop --> (; ; ). As you can see inside body of loop (the expression, that will be executed until loop is valid) I have just b = b + "#", which means, that my first "for" loop will do looping :) 8 times and will store inside "b" variable THE LAST VALUE (it will be ########), you can check this out in a single sheet (and you will see, that this looping is still going vertically, but the point is that it stores the LAST VALUE)

**{ b = b + "#"}**      //**that is the body of first loop which is described clearly above

**for (let a = 0; a < size; a++)**   //**inside second loop, we create the same routine, and proceed inside that loop with value of "b" from first loop. Notice, that first loop is enclosed {}, so it act independantly.

**{**

**if (a % 2 == 0)**            //**just condition, which allows us to distribute different strings (rows) of code (I hope you understand what is inside parenthesis

**{console.log (" " + b)}**      //**Since we want to see our chessboard we should print this out onto screen, for that we use "console.log" but again, notice, that here WE DON'T change value of variable "b", we just operate with it, but it will stay the same "########"

**else{**

**console.log (b)}**         //** And if "if" fails, we will proceed with "########" value, which is NEW origin of "b" variable

**}**